# What is the differences between to install docker-compose by binary or by pip install

Tags: redhat, docker, yum, containers, pip

We have two option that we can use in order to install the docker-compose

We already installed docker , and now we want to install docker compose on **production environment**

One option is by binary docker-compose

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

the second option is by pip as the following

```
$ yum install epel-release
Install python-pip
$ yum install -y python-pip
Then install Docker Compose:
$ pip install docker-compose
```

Are the first option that installed the docker-compose by binary is a ***good enough*** as the docker-compose that installed by PIP?

Comment: The biggest difference, in my experience, is that with the second method you can easily `pip install --upgrade docker-compose`. That being said, if you are talking about the exact same version of docker-compose, either method has the exact same result.